# PL/SQL: trigger error on altering insert data

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to write trigger for the table of books. For this table,

```
create table books (
    isbn VARCHAR(13) CHECK (LENGTH (isbn) = 10 or LENGTH (isbn) = 13),
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (isbn)
);
```

I want to write a trigger that when isbn of length 10 is to be inserted, change its format to the 13-digit one according to the following rules:

1. Last digit is removed
2. Added 978 to front
3. Added check bit that is calculated by the formula

   CHECK_BIT = (10 - (x1 + 3*x2 + x3 + 3*x4 + ... + x11 + 3*x12) mod 10) mod 10

Code:

```
create or replace trigger isbnFormatChange
before insert on books
for each row
begin
  if (length (:new.isbn) = 10) then
    :new.isbn := substr (:new.isbn, 1, 9);
    :new.isbn := concat (978, :new.isbn);
    :new.isbn := concat (:new.isbn, mod ((10 - mod ((to_number (substr (:new.isbn, 1, 1)) + 3 * to_number (substr (:new.isbn, 2, 1)) + to_number (substr (:new.isbn, 3, 1)) + 3 * to_number (substr (:new.isbn, 4, 1)) + to_number (substr (:new.isbn, 5, 1)) + 3 * to_number (substr (:new.isbn, 6, 1)) + to_number (substr (:new.isbn, 7, 1)) + 3 * to_number (substr (:new.isbn, 8, 1)) + to_number (substr (:new.isbn, 9, 1)) + 3 * to_number (substr (:new.isbn, 10, 1)) + to_number (substr (:new.isbn, 11, 1)) + 3 * to_number (substr (:new.isbn, 12, 1))), 10)), 10));
  end if;
end;
```

but it gives the following error:

```
Error(5,5): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(5,63): PLS-00330: invalid use of type name or subtype name
```

I think I did step 3 wrong (formula part)

Comment: don't think, be sure that problem is there because except than formula part everything at least in case of syntax is fine

Comment: @Farhęg line 5 is the line where i try to implement formula, so error is there (at least, according to sql developer)

Comment: Oracle's `convert()` function does not do what you think it does. It converts a string from one character set to another character set. If you need to convert a character string to a number use `to_number()` or `cast()` function.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov changed to to_number(), still gives the same error

Comment: Of course it does. Here is the syntax of [to_number()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm#i79512) function, and here is the syntax of [cast()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm#i1269136) function

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov oh, i forgot to delete int in one instance, sorry, thanks

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev I've replaced all `convert` with `to_number`, you can see it in my answer. It works (I've checked), maybe, you need to do that more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `convert` is used for converting different character types to each other. To convert character string to number use function `to_number`. So you just need to replace in your code all `convert (int, ...)` with `to_number()` function:

```
create or replace trigger isbnFormatChange
before insert on books
for each row
begin
  if (length (:new.isbn) = 10) then
    :new.isbn := substr (:new.isbn, 1, 9);
    :new.isbn := concat (978, :new.isbn);
    :new.isbn := concat (:new.isbn, mod ((10 - mod ((to_number(substr (:new.isbn, 1, 1)) + 3 * to_number(substr (:new.isbn, 2, 1)) + to_number(substr (:new.isbn, 3, 1)) + 3 * to_number(substr (:new.isbn, 4, 1)) + to_number( substr (:new.isbn, 5, 1)) + 3 * to_number( substr (:new.isbn, 6, 1)) + to_number(substr (:new.isbn, 7, 1)) + 3 * to_number( substr (:new.isbn, 8, 1)) + to_number( substr (:new.isbn, 9, 1)) + 3 * to_number( substr (:new.isbn, 10, 1)) + to_number(substr (:new.isbn, 11, 1)) + 3 * to_number( substr (:new.isbn, 12, 1))), 10)), 10));
  end if;
end;
/
```

`convert` function in documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620
`to_number` function in documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions211.htm#SQLRF06140